# Proof of Thom's Cobordism theorem, the last step

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of Thom's Cobordism theorem. At this point I have the spectrum $MO$, and I already understood how we can compute it's cohomology and we will have that $H^*(MO)\cong \mathcal{A}\otimes M$, where $M\subset H^*(MO)$. Everything here is taken with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients. Now I am trying to understand how we will have that $MO$ decomposes as a sum of eilenberg-maclane spectra and then we can compute $\pi_*(MO)$, which will give us the cobordism ring by the Pontrjagin Thom isomorphism. I am fairly new to the concept of spectrum so there may be some properties about them I am missing and hence would like to understand them.

So now pick a basis $\{d_i\}$ of $M$. By representability of cohomology each $d_i$ gives a map of spectra $MO\rightarrow \Sigma^{|d_i|}K(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ and putting all of these maps together we obtain a map

$$MO\rightarrow \bigvee_{i} \Sigma^{|d_i|}K(\mathbb{Z}_2)$$

Then in the lecture notes I have been reading, it's claimed that since $H^*(K(\mathbb{Z}_2))\cong \mathcal{A}$ and $H^*(MO)\cong \mathcal{A}\otimes M$ then this map is an isomorphism in cohomology with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients.  I am not quite seeing why this is true. Do we also have that $H^*(\Sigma^{|d_i|}K(\mathbb{Z}_2))\cong \mathcal{A}$ and we use something like $H^*(\Sigma^{|d_i|}K(\mathbb{Z}_2))\cong \bigoplus _{d_i\in \mathcal{A}}\mathcal{A}$?

Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Just commenting on the suspension question, suspension does preserve reduced cohomology but shifts the degree up by one.